# Find occurrence of a substring in string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query to getresults from my database:

```
MATCH(`Text2`) AGAINST ('$s')
```

I want to get only results when there is a full match of the string, like when on google when you search between quotes "".

How can I do this with Match/MySQL?

EG: Query is "ab cd"

```
ID | Text
1    ab cd
2    aab cda
3    aab a cd
```

Row 1 and 2 should be returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT FROM your_table WHERE Text2 LIKE '%yourstring%';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:: 
If you need the wild search irrespective to the cases ::

```
SELECT FROM LOWER(mytable) WHERE LOWER(Text2) LIKE LOWER('%yourstring%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP` for this purpose too.

```
SELECT *
FROM `tableName`
WHERE `columnName` REGEXP 'ab cd';
```